# glib errors on cygwin

Tags: compiling, cygwin, shared-library, glib

I want to compile and install geany text editor in Windows 7 by using cygwin.
I follow the usual way to compile and install C source:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

the configure script was successfully running and give me no errors.In the `make` step i have the following errors :

```
ctags.c:23:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
#include <glib.h>
```

I have installed pkg-config and also add the pkg-config output to makefile by doing the
following:

```
CFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)
CXXFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)
LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)
```

This is the output of the pkg-config

```
$pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lpcre -lintl - liconv -lpcre


$ pkg-config --libs glib-2.0
-lglib-2.0 -lintl -lpcre -lintl -liconv -lpcre
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add compiler flags to configure script, so that they are propagated to all Makefile files.

```
./configure CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include" CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include" LDFLAGS="-lglib-2.0 -lintl -lpcre -lintl -liconv -lpcre"
```